# System.currentMillis to keeptrackof expired items in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, redis

I am writing an unitility which will check if the items added in last 10 seconds exc ends the limit of count 10. My app will throw an exception if more than 10 items gets added in then list within 10 secs. Redis doesn't have a mechanism to add time to live on each element in set or list. To workaround this I am storing current Millis in concatinated format on each call in Redis. Whenever user add an item in list I check if the 10 the items time stamp and currenttimestamp difference is greater than 10 sec I let it through. If not I block the operation.

Although this works I am looking for a better way to do this. And need a feedback if there can be any issue in this process

Comment: You can use Redis [Sorted Sets](http://redis.io/topics/data-types#sorted-sets) to do so. Sorted sets use a numeric score for ordering. By using the timestamp you get that feature. From what I read, you don't mention any distributed/remote aspect, so maybe a common Java in-memory util would fit your case best.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is an LRU (Least Recently Used) Cache. 
There are plenty of implementations of this on the web if you search.

Here is a very simple example of how to accomplish implementing one:

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public LRUCache<K, V> extends LinkedHashMap<K, V> {
    private int cacheSize;

    public LRUCache(int cacheSize) {
      super(16, 0.75, true);
      this.cacheSize = cacheSize;
    }

    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K, V> eldest) {
      return size() >= cacheSize;
   }
}
```

With this, you can add an item to the cash and the oldest entry will be removed.
You can also check if an item exists in the cache to determine if it has been stored recently in the cache.

Hope that helps.

Comment: actually my question is bit different.  oldest entry is not important. My requirment is "less than 10 sec if 10+ entries are getting added" I need to recognize it and throw an exception. And m app is destributed so your code will not help me.